# Why am I unable to wrap dynamic arrays with shared_ptr despite using C++ 17?

Tags: c++, arrays, clang, c++17, shared-ptr

**I have C++17** turned on and clang from Android NDK and I expect the below to work

```
std::shared_ptr<int[]> sp(new int[5]());
```

but I get

> error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::shared_ptr<int []>'

How do I fix this ? This works fine on MSVC

Comment: What Clang version? This works since Clang 11.

Comment: Instead of explicit `new` I suggest using `std::make_shared`. And instead of using a C style array you'd better use `std::array` or `std::vector`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat that probably explains it. The NDK I'm using ships with clang 9

Comment: @RoQuOTriX it's a C++ 17 feature

Comment: @datenwolf I have specifc reason

Comment: @RoQuOTriX dynamic arrays wrapped by a shared_ptr was not possible pre C++17. 
std::shared_ptr<int[]>

Comment: @datenwolf I need to able to pass the same information from the source that is over an ABI stable bridge so int* only. Using std::vector and std::array will force me to copy it which I don't want to do.

Comment: for pre c++17 you'd need to use `std::shared_ptr<int> sp(new int[5](), [](int* p){ delete[] p; });`. Note that shared pointers to arrays don't require clang 11 but libc++ 11, clang with libstdc++ works in earlier versions (though I'm not sure if you end up with the correct deleter being generated in this case)

Comment: @AlanBirtles my question  says I'm using C++17 and still hit the error in CLANG

Comment: just because you are asking for C++17 doesn't mean it is fully implemented in the compiler and standard library, as stated above it looks like `shared_ptr`s to arrays weren't implemented in libc++ until version 11 so if you're using that it wont work. See the line for `P0414R2` at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support

Comment: @rstr1112: I don't think ABI concerns are justified, you're using `std::shared_ptr` already. And whereever you need to expose the naked pointer (`int*`) you can just invoke the `std::{array,vector}::data()` accessor, i.e. `auto sp = std::make_shared<std::array<int, 5>>(); /* … */; foo(sp->data());`.

Comment: @datenwolf : I don't mean I'll pass shared_ptr across the boundary. I'll wrap the raw pointer with a shared_ptr once it crosses the bridge